# Create Executable from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to do something which should be simple, but I am having difficulty finding the resources in. I want to create either a .VB or .CS simple script in visual studio without a form interface to later be used an an executable to be ran in windows. I created the script in .vbs but since that is not a compilable language I can't make it a .exe from it.

The final idea is for the .exe to simply create some folders and move some files around without any popups for the client.  Here is some of the simple .vbs code I made I am just trying to migrate over into Visual Studio compliable format.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Delete a Folder
If fso.FolderExists("C:\Program Files (x86)\Something") then
    fso.Deletefolder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Something", True
End IF

fso.CopyFolder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Somethingelse", "C:\temp\Destination", True
```

Comment: vba is not used in visual-studio.  It should be vb.net. I adjusted it for you.

Comment: check out console apps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019

Comment: And `.vbs` is VBScript too so the VBA tag was doubly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to create a Console application and then to change the output type to "Windows Application" (in a C# project). Such an application will neither show a console nor a form window.

To change the output type, right click the project to open its properties. On the "Application" page there is a combo box named "Output type:". Select "Windows Application" from the drop down list.

It's the same in a VB project, except that the combo box is named "Application type:". Also you must select the "Startup object:". Most probably it will be "Sub Main".

Comment: Thanks for the Tip. In my Visual studio I did find the "Windows Application" for the C# project, but for the VB Project I have "Windows Forms Application" and "Windows Service" I assume the "Windows Forms Application" would be my best bet?

Comment: Yes, the exact wording depends on the Framework version.

Comment: That was completely the trick! I made what I needed in C# and it all worked great. Thanks!!

Comment: @Chuck The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer. Do this by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. It will also help future readers and give you a couple of points. Upvotes are also appreciated.